# Sending notification to an application from AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a requirement where I want to send notifications to a `REST` service from `AWS` every time a VM is started/stopped. Is it possible to achieve this using `CloudWatch` or any other `AWS` service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can do it by using AWS Lambda in combination with AWS Cloudtrail.

Enable Cloudtrail and make it write to a S3 bucket. When a new object is written to that bucket by Cloudtrail, S3 can be made to trigger a lambda function.

In the lambda function, you parse the cloudtrail log and if you find a startinstance or stopinstance, you send a notification.

It may sound difficult, but it is pretty straightforward. I did this for a different reason. Check my answer here: [Mandatory tagging when launching EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31867803/mandatory-tagging-when-launching-ec2-instance)

Comment: It seems that this is the only solution at this point. However I was expecting that this will be possible using CloudWatch and SNS services.

Comment: It seems it is possible to achieve this using cloudwatch and lambda as described here - docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html