# How to connect IAM login name with an EC2 instance?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, boto3

I am using the boto3 Python3 module provided by AWS.  I'm able to extract the security key name and the various tags associated with an EC2 instance.  Unfortunately, none of that information tells me who created the instance.

Is there a way to use AWS IAM to see what active instances were created by a user?

Comment: No. Unfortunately the IAM user who launched the instance is not part of instance attributes. See how I solved this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31867803/mandatory-tagging-when-launching-ec2-instance