# Enforce Tag Value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I was trying a policy to predefine the tag value so that the instance should not be created if you don't create required tag and its value while you launch i,e the instance should have costcenter and dept as tags and value should be 115 and the prod. Then only we should be able to launch the instance. Can someone help me in this policy.

```html
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:Describe*",
        "ec2:GetConsole*"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:RunInstances"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:region::image/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:subnet/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:network-interface/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:security-group/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:key-pair/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:instance/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:RequestTag/costcenter": "115",
          "aws:RequestTag/dept": "prod"
        },
        "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
          "aws:TagKeys": [
            "costcenter",
            "dept"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:CreateTags"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:*/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "ec2:CreateAction": "RunInstances"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It is not possible. See my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31867803/mandatory-tagging-when-launching-ec2-instance

Answer (score 0):

you can try this sample which will deny action if only one tag is present, you can modify the code with your tags multiple blocks state for multiple policy :

```
{
    "Sid": "AllowLaunchOnlyWithRequiredTags1",
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:accountid:instance/*",
    "Condition": {
        "Null": {"aws:RequestTag/costcenter": "true"}
    }
},
{
    "Sid": "AllowLaunchOnlyWithRequiredTags2",
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:accountid:instance/*",
    "Condition": {
        "Null": {"aws:RequestTag/stack": "true"}
    }
}
```

Furthermore you can list the tag enforcement as :

```
"Condition": {
    "StringEquals": {
      "aws:RequestTag/costcenter": "115",
      "aws:RequestTag/stack": "prod"
     },
     "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
         "aws:TagKeys": ["costcenter","stack"]
     }
   }
```

[According to AWS Documents for `ForAllValues`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_multi-value-conditions.html#reference_policies_multi-value-conditions-examples)

> the ForAllValues qualifier requires all requested values to be listed
>   in the policy

Another way You could do something using `StringLike` or `StringNotLike`, but it's limited to wildcards if that works for you.

Something Like :

```
"Statement": [
{
  "Sid": "DenyMissingTags",
  "Effect": "Deny",
  "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:accountid:instance/*",
  "Condition": {
    "StringLike": [
      "aws:RequestTag/costcenter": "*",
      "aws:RequestTag/stack": "*"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

[Refer this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements.html#Conditions_String)

Comment: I am trying to enforce tag with value The first block above could enforce the use of tag irrespective of values. when I try to use second block It is not taking that condition for restricting the values

Comment: It was sample for 2 part code , it is for compulsorily having 2 values , you need to modify it as per your needs

Comment: Yes buddy..!! I know that I need to modify what i am saying is that even if we dont have those compulsorily 2values tags it is allowing to launch instance.