# AWS Lambda Python Get Latest S3 Bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, bucket

I'm writing a Lambda function which attaches a policy to the latest bucket. The script attaches the policy to the named bucket, but I'm not too sure how to get the name of the latest bucket created. Any ideas are appreciated :). The current code is below.

```
import boto3
import json

client = boto3.client('s3')
bucket_name = '*'
bucket_policy = {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [{
                "Sid": "DenyS3PublicObjectACL",
                "Effect": "Deny",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action": ["s3:PutObjectAcl"],
                "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::%s/*" #% bucket_name,
                "Condition": {
                    "StringEqualsIgnoreCaseIfExists": {
                        "s3:x-amz-acl": [
                            "public-read",
                            "public-read-write",
                            "authenticated-read"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }


bucket_policy = json.dumps(bucket_policy) # Converting the policy into a JSON string.

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = client.put_bucket_policy(Bucket=bucket_name, ConfirmRemoveSelfBucketAccess=True, Policy=bucket_policy)
```

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31867803/mandatory-tagging-when-launching-ec2-instance. In your case, instead of RunInstances, look at CreateBucket API in CloudTrail. The response will contain the bucket name.

Comment: It feels like you are trying to solve the wrong problem, here.  Nobody can do anything to your buckets unless you grant them permission to... so don't grant anyone permission to put objects into buckets, without constraining their grant to require appropriate ACLs.

Comment: I want to attach a certain policy to all buckets though. Just in case, some privilege escalation occurred etc.

Comment: Anyone know how to pass the bucket name into the Lambda function? Still quite confused.